# Can't see my changes after rebuild kernel

Tags: drivers

I have downloaded Ubuntu version for OMAP4, compiled it and worked with it.
Then I changed one of the drivers code (`I2C`) - and added prints from the driver

I did the following to re-build the kernel

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules clean
$ do_tools=false skipabi=true skipmodule=true dpkg-buildpackage -B -aarmhf -uc -us
```

I can't see my changes (prints) while loading the kernel, even though the the relevant file was recompiled.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that it was actually your new kernel that loaded? Use `uname -a` and verify the compile date and time and any local name.

Comment: You are, it's not loaded even I do the following: 
$ cd ~/var-som-om44.deb/
$ scp <yourname>@<your build system ip>:<your build folder>/*.deb ./
$ sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
$ sudo dpkg -i *3.4.0-1489.28_armhf.deb
and rebbot,
I have to mention that I used this directory and version before, do you think that this is the reason?